# AI model for arbitrary text prediction?

Tags: tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, text-processing

Not sure if this is the right place, a friend told me to go here. I want to make an AI that takes in text during training, and afterwards gives new text based on what the user "samples" it (this is *not* for a chat program).

For example, if I entered the following for training:

```
abc123,test,example
def456,work,coolio
```

and the following for sampling:

```
ghi789,what
```

It should output something **based** on what it knows, but not an exact replica of what it knows (unless of course the input was used for training).

Is this possible? Is there an existing model for this? I was thinking char-rnn but it doesn't allow custom input during sampling.

Sorry if this is the wrong place or if this isn't allowed on this site. I have researched extensively but can't find anything. I know a small bit of TensorFlow but not enough to start from scratch.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A character RNN would be a good place to start with this. If you're new to the field it's definitely the best place to start because there are a lot of tutorials and examples to help you get off the ground, and because we know they work.

Read Karpathy's excellent blog & paper on this: http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/

You certainly can provide custom input during sampling. Once the network is trained you can sample in a number of different ways, and in fact, you have to provide at least the first character as "custom input".

A typical sampling pattern would be to randomly select a first character as input to the first RNN sequence step. Then the RNN will produce a probability distribution over the alphabet which you can randomly sample the next character from.

For the 2nd character, let's say you sampled from the RNNs probability distribution, then the randomly selected character becomes the input of the next RNN sequence step. And so on with the following characters.

Notice that there is nothing stopping you from seeding a sequence of multiple characters, ignoring the RNNs output at each step, and then sampling the RNNs output after some input sequence has completed. Thus achieving your goal of starting with a custom input sequence that then gets continued. I expect that this approach will work quite well for you.